# How to add a new obj from html in django

Tags: python, django

So im trying to make this page where i add new category which only has name. But when i try it, i just get a "non-string type" as the name. So it works i guess just doesn't take whatever i give it in my input in html.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" id = "category-create-name" name= 
"category_name">
<input type="submit" class="login-button" value="Post">
```

Model:

```
class Category(models.Model):
id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Form:

```
class CategoryCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Category
    fields = ('name',)
    widgets = {
        'category_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Name', 'id':'category-create-name'}),
        }
```

View:

```
class CategoryCreateView(CreateView):
form_class = CategoryCreateForm
template_name = 'product/new_category.html'
success_url = '/dashboard/'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things I see here. First in your form. In the `widgets` attribute of `class Meta`, the keys in that dictionary need to be a field name that is in your `fields` attribute. In other words you need to change `'category_name'` to `'name'`. Second, in your template that is used for the view. You seem to be manually defining a separate input field rather than the one that your view and form are expecting. You should just define the form in your template like this:

```
<form method="POST">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{ form_as_p }}
   <input type="submit" class="login-button" value="Post">
</form>
```

In the template `{{ form.as_p }}` will take the form that you gave to your view, and automatically create it in the html when it is being rendered to the page.

Comment: Yeah but i want to make it as an <input> so i can give it a class to change how it looks cuz im using css for it

Comment: Oh but changing the "cateogry_name" to just "name" and using name="name" in input works. Thank you

Comment: @Aleksa doing the `{{ form.as_p }}` will automatically create the html `<input>` element in your template with the class, id, and any other value that you defined in the widget `attrs` argument in your form. That is what django forms are designed to do.

Comment: Oh i just tryed it and its as you say... Thank you again, im kinda new to django and all this

Comment: You're welcome. If you have any more questions feel free to ask.

Comment: How can i remove the label that i get when using {{ form.as_p }}

Comment: There are a couple of ways to do that.  The first, you can just use the form fields themselves in the template. So instead of doing `{{ form.as_p }}`, you can do something like `{{ form.<fieldname> }}` which will get the input field from your form for the fieldname that you put in. For your case it would be `{{ form.name }}`. The other way is in your form class you can set another attribute in your `class Meta:` called `labels`. It is a dictionary of field names and you can set what appears in the label. If you set it like `labels = { 'name' : '' }` it will not render a label for that field

Comment: To clarify incase it isn't clear. Using `{{ form.as_p }}` in a template will render the entire form, labels and all, into the template with each label/field combo surrounded in `<p>` tags. If you just do `{{ form.<fieldname> }}`, it will only render the input field from the given field name.  In your case, since your form only has the one field it doesn't make that much of a difference. If you did this with a larger form though, you would need to add more `{{ form.<fieldname> }}` tags into your template for each field in your form that you want displayed.

Comment: Everything you listed works, do you maybe have discord or something where i can msg you if i get stuck somewhere again